# Python iterate over stdin line by line using input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-3.5

I am trying to get multiple names separated by newlines from the console and put them into a variable. Let's assume I want to get input from the terminal forever (I'll add some code to break out of the loop later). I know how to do it with a while loop and recursion, but I would like to be able to do it with a for loop.

In the below example when I get `"peter"` as input from the terminal I get each letter rather than a whole line at a time:

```
for name in input():
    print(name)
```

Now, if I use `sys.stdin` the `name` variable becomes `"peter\n"`:

```
for name in sys.stdin:
    print(name)
```

Is there a easy way to get `input()` to give `"name"` a whole line rather than individual characters? Or just by the nature of using `for in` I am going to be iterating through the characters in the input? Are there any inherent risks/problems with getting input in this fashion? Is there a "standard" way of getting input in a situation like this?

I am using Python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: `input()` returns a string which is an iterable, so therefore when you try and iterate over it you are getting each character one by one.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. input() returns a string. So does sys.stdin return a buffer that is iterated line by line?

Comment: Because sys.stdin returns a file like object which, when iterated through, will contain each individual line of the input.

Comment: @PeterH [`sys.stdin` isn't a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.stdin#sys.stdin), it actually is a file object which is used by the system to get the standard input, therefore `for name in sys.stdin` behaves like it would do on a file: reading it line by line.

Comment: Cool makes sense. If I am using 'for name in sys.stdin' that would exit the loop when the input ends correct?

Comment: @PeterH only if you include a break condition inside the for loop such as `name == 'exit'`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can wrap `stdin` to strip the newlines; if you can strip all trailing whitespace (usually okay), then it's just:

```
for name in map(str.rstrip, sys.stdin):
    ...
```

You're on Py3, so that works as is; if you're on Py2, you'll need to add an import, `from future_builtins import map`, so you get a lazy, generator based `map` (that yields the lines as they're requested, rather than slurping `stdin` until it ends, then returning a `list` of all the lines).

If you need to limit to newlines, a generator expression can do it:

```
for name in (line.rstrip("\r\n") for line in sys.stdin):
    ...
```

or with an import to allow `map` to push work to C layer for (slightly) faster code (a matter of 30-some nanoseconds per line faster than the genexpr, but still 40 ns per line slower than the argumentless option at the top of this answer):

```
from operator import methodcaller

for name in map(methodcaller('rstrip', '\r\n'), sys.stdin):
    ...
```

Like the first solution, on Py2, make sure to get the `map` from `future_builtins`.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend you this, but you can create a generator to be used in a `for` loop to iterate through input line by line:

```
def getlines():
    while True:
        yield input()

for name in getlines():
    print(name)
    ## Remember to break out of the loop at some point
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I am trying to do it more than one time with each name separated by a newline in the terminal.

Comment: This seems perfect for the simplest line-by-line reading. And the iterator could be enhanced to split that line into smaller parts, yielding those parts one by one.